# Pusher for Android Implementation

Tags: android, pusher

I'm trying to implement a pusher service in my Android app, doesn't have access to the server just copying from an iOS app previous implementation. Everything works fine in connection process but when subscribe to a private channel the authentication fails with:

```
"com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://authorization_url"
```

The implementation goes like this:

```
    HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(PUSHER_AUTH_URL);
    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setEncrypted(true).setWssPort(443).setAuthorizer(authorizer);
    pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_KEY, options);
    pusher.connect(new com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {

                        if (change.getCurrentState() == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                            Channel channel = pusher.subscribePrivate(PUSH_CHANNEL, new PrivateChannelEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAuthenticationFailure(String s, Exception e) {
                                    Log.w("PUSHER", "Channel subscription authorization failed");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String s) {
                                    Log.w("PUSHER", "Channel subscription authorization succeeded");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onEvent(String s, String s2, String s3) {
                                    Log.w("PUSHER", "An event with name " + s2 + " was delivered!!");
                                }
                            }, "my-event");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                        Log.w("PUSHER", "There was a problem connecting with code " + code + " and message " + message);
                    }
                }, ConnectionState.ALL);
```

UPDATE

I'm sure that the problem is with the authentication, there is a function call in iOS version that set some headers to the channel subscription or something like that:

```
(void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher willAuthorizeChannel:(PTPusherChannel *)channel withRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request;
{
    [request addAuthorizationHeadersForUser:self.credentials.user];

}
```

Im trying to figure out where to add the headers in android, try to add it to the authorizer but nothing change:

```
authorizer.setHeaders(addMapAuthorizationHeaders());
```

Any idea of what is the equivalent in Android of that iOS function: willAuthorizeChannel??

Comment: Assuming that `https://authorization_url` is actually a proper url in your code, it's quite likely that either you don't have internet, or you didn't include the `INTERNET` permission.

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem, the request goes fine and the server is returning the exception, I'm pretty suer that it is a authorization problem. Updating the question now.

Comment: @labreu Any chance you could share the implementation of `addAuthorizationHeadersForUser:`? I am trying to get Pusher authentication to work on iOS and I believe that this might be the part that I am missing.

Comment: @erik its the second part of my answer, also take a look at the comments of my answer and the other answer here for iOS code..but basically its a map with key/value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok solved, it was what I thought, the HttpAuthorizer needed a set of headers that you can set directly when creating it like:

```
HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(PUSHER_AUTH_URL);
authorizer.setHeaders(MY_AUTH_HEADERS); //a HashMap with the headers
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setEncrypted(true).setWssPort(443).setAuthorizer(authorizer);
pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_KEY, options);
```

And with that works fine, in case somebody have a similar problem.

EDIT:
this is how to set the authorization headers. It's a Map set to "Key" "Value" pair for example:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getMapAuthorizationHeaders() {
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> authHeader = new HashMap<>();
        authHeader.put("HeaderKey1", "HeaderValue1");
        authHeader.put("HeaderKey2", "HeaderValue2");
        return authHeader;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So the pusher config will be like:

```
authorizer.setHeaders(getMapAuthorizationHeaders());
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you MY_AUTH_HEADERS contains? I am trying to solve the exact same issue you had

Comment: - (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)pusher willAuthorizeChannel:(PTPusherChannel *)channel withRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{
 NSString* authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token token=\"%@\"", self.userAccessToken];
 [request setValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
}

HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(baseUrl + "pusher/auth");
HashMap<String, String> pusherAuthHeaders = new HashMap<>(); 
   pusherAuthHeaders.put("Authorization", "Token token=\"" + session.getAccessToken() + "\"");
        authorizer.setHeaders(pusherAuthHeaders)

Still get file not found

Comment: Nope, nothing special, if you're getting some auth error should be a problem with the headers i think, in my case I use a "Authorization" header where sending "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("username" + ":" + "password").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP); but that's specific to my server, maybe it has something to do with pusher, I don't know coz I'm not dealing with server side code, but if you have a iOS counterpart working the headers should be the same for both

Comment: pusherAuthHeaders.put("Authorization", "Token token=\"" + session.getAccessToken() + "\"");  check that header, the value sounds weird to me. Anyway at least you know that the problem is in authorization, check the headers values and it should be fine with the right ones

Comment: What I get is
Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of {######.#####} :private-online-session-{hex GUID here}, but got {another HEX GUID without dashes in it}

All public and presence subscriptions are working fine, I can't get a private session to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this as well... the solution is simple.

First check this out: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pusher/client/util/HttpAuthorizer.java

Then implement the abstract interface Authorizer and override the authorize method with your own code and that's it, you get the same thing as on the iOS.

Some snippet to get you started (with a custom constructor):

```
CustomSocketHttpAuthorizer authorizer = new CustomSocketHttpAuthorizer(ServerComm.API_MAIN_LINK + ServerComm.API_LINK_PUSHER_AUTH, pusherServerAuthTimeStamp, MessageActivity.this);

PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setAuthorizer(authorizer).setEncrypted(true);;

clientPusher = new Pusher(ServerComm.PUSHER_CLIENT_KEY, options);

clientPusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() .....
```